# PowerShell EPPlus unable to change Backgroundcolor of Cells

Tags: excel, powershell, epplus

I am creating an Excel Document using EPPlus. It is working, but I am not able to change the Background Color of Cells.
I use the following code for it:

```
Worksheet.Cells[row,column].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.rgb = (255,0,0)
```

Everytime I execute the script it says:

> "rgb" is a read-only property

When I try to set the

```
Worksheet.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = xxx
```

I get the same error:

> "BackgroundColor" is a read-only property

I did not find more options, where you might change the Color or change the property to writeable...
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my PowerShell Excel module that wraps EPPlus and makes interaction really easy.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/

[image]

```
$xlfile = "$env:TEMP\test.xlsx"
rm $xlfile -ErrorAction Ignore

$pkg = ps | select company, Handles| Export-Excel $xlfile -PassThru

$ws = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]

Set-Format -WorkSheet $ws -Range "B2:B2" -BackgroundColor Red
Set-Format -WorkSheet $ws -Range "B5:B5" -BackgroundColor Green

Close-ExcelPackage $pkg -Show
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the color like this.

```
Worksheet.Cells[row,column].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
Worksheet.Cells[row,column].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not working for me. It says ")" is missing..             Your code is in c# right? I want to use the same in PowerShell..

Comment: Yes this is C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EPPlus dll directly into Powershell through Add-Type, then you can use the below code

```
$ExcelPackage = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage

$Sheet1 = $ExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")
$Sheet1.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = 1        # 1 denotes solid color
$Sheet1.Cells["A1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(147,205,221))
```